# needs to return formatted array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hello I have a text file formatted like:

```
ITEM SKU PRICE QTY SUBTOTAL Classic Flipbook
Design Name:
Frosted
Title:
Merry Christmas
Title 2:
Something
Title 3:
Files:
55c6155a19622: _20150711_200519.JPG
3x2 $18.00 1 $18.00 Classic Flipbook
Design Name:
Bouquet
Title:
Title 2:
Title 3:
something
Files:
55c6157ebb6b3: _20150712_070009.JPG
3x2 $18.00 1 $18.00 Subtotal $36.00 Sales Tax (9.25%) $3.96 Shipping &
Handling $6.62 Grand Total $46.58
```

I need to return below formatted output as associative array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [design] => Frosted
            [title_1] => Merry Christmas
            [title_2] => Something
            [title_3] => 
            [file_id] => 55c6155a19622
            [file_name] => _20150711_200519.JPG
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [design] => Bouquet
            [title_1] => 
            [title_2] => 
            [title_3] => 
            [file_id] => 
            [file_name] => 
        )

)
```

NOTE: Needs to read file and than make an array like above

Comment: So you have the above text file stored in a variable, and you're looking to parse and format the text to be like the array you provided?

Comment: I'm also confused on where you're getting the structure of your desired output array from. You have, for example, a key named `title_1` in your array, but nothing that seems to correspond with the text file provided.

Comment: actually if desire input have nothing corresponding value than it will be blank but i need above formatted structured aray from input file

Comment: you understood proper

Answer (score 0):

If it is the formatted associated array you want then try this:

```
$AssociatedArray = ['design' => (yourDesignInput), 'title_1' => (inputtedTitle1), 'title_2' => (inputtedTitle2), 'title_3' => (inputtedTitle3), 'file_id' => (inputtedFileID), 'file_name' => (inputtedFileName)];
```

Comment: yes but needs to create array for all keys with their desired values thats the matter..as you mentioned its right structure but i need yourDesignInput,inputtedTitle1,inputtedTitle2 etc. dynamic values from input file

Comment: I need a variable for that. You only use text.

Comment: i dont have that code actually code needs to create ...can you suggest me to create this array directly from text file...below is the text file only i have.ITEM SKU PRICE QTY SUBTOTAL Classic Flipbook
Design Name:
Frosted
Title:
Merry Christmas
Title 2:
Something
Title 3:
Files:
55c6155a19622: _20150711_200519.JPG
3x2 $18.00 1 $18.00 Classic Flipbook
Design Name:
Bouquet
Title:
Title 2:
Title 3:
something
Files:
55c6157ebb6b3: _20150712_070009.JPG
3x2 $18.00 1 $18.00 Subtotal $36.00 Sales Tax (9.25%) $3.96 Shipping &
Handling $6.62 Grand Total $46.58

Comment: yeah i used this..but still not getting desired output..let me try..thanks for your prompt effort for it..i will ask if i need any help in this again.